# SFINAE To detect non-member function existence

Tags: c++, sfinae

Does anybody know of a method for specializing a template depending on whether a non-member method is defined? I know there are numerous ways for specializing if a member function exists, but I've never seen a non-member example. The specific problem is specializing the operator<< for shared_ptr to apply the operator<< if the operator<< is defined for T, and printing the mere pointer location otherwise. It would be great if all classes defined operator<< as a member, but unfortunately many use free functions. I'm imagining something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
typename enable_if< ??? ,std::ostream &>::type operator<<( std::ostream & os, const shared_ptr<T> & ptr )
{
  if(ptr)
   return os << *ptr;
  else
   return os << "<NULL>";
}

template <typename T>
typename disable_if< ??? ,std::ostream &>::type operator<<( std::ostream & os, const shared_ptr<T> & ptr )
{
  if(ptr)
   return os << static_cast<intptr_t>( ptr.get() );
  else
   return os << "<NULL>";
}
```

Edit: For posterity, here was the working solution. Note that boost::shared_ptr already has a default operator<< that outputs the address, so the disable_if is unnecessary. Since the operator<< returns a reference, this works. For the general case I suspect this would have to be tailored to reflect the return type of the function in question.

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c< boost::is_reference<decltype(*static_cast<std::ostream *>(0) << *static_cast<T *>(0) )>::value, std::ostream &>::type operator<<( std::ostream & os, const boost::shared_ptr<T> & ptr )
{
  if(ptr)
   return os << *ptr;
  else
   return os << "<NULL>";
}
```

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312486/c-how-to-print-an-object-of-uknown-type/3312934#3312934) may be helpful to you. It's a different approach to the problem, but same result. If the operator isn't defined, it goes to a generic output function where you can do whatever you want. Not posting as an answer since it doesn't answer the title question , but I'd recommend this one.

Comment: You'll rarely find classes implementing the stream-insertion and -extraction operators as member functions since it's the *stream* that needs to be the left-hand operand, not the class.

Comment: Good call Rob. I didn't think that one through.

Comment: Just gonna say, I don't think that you need any of the enable_if stuff. I think that it'll just work with the decltype.

Comment: DeadMG, in this case you're certainly right, but I think that's a fortunate consequence of the function we want to conditionally instantiate (operator<< for shared_ptr<T>) and the function we're querying the existence of (operator<< for T) having the same return value. In the general case I'm not convinced you can do it without the enable_if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C++0x, you could simply use decltype.

```
template<typename Char, typename CharTraits, typename T>
        decltype(
            *(std::basic_ostream<Char, CharTraits>*)(nullptr) << *(T*)(nullptr)
        )
```

That'll certainly cause a substitution failure if a T cannot be output. You could probably do something similar in C++03, but I'm not sure how.

Edit: Just realised that the decltype expression doesn't actually produce a true or false value and won't compile. But you get the picture. Try this.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. For posterity  I'll included my complete code above.

Comment: This doesn't provide a general solution at all.