# Non-member variable detection

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to use SFINAE to detect non-member variable existance. Basically it suits my needs to test whether a *name* was declared and can be seen in the actual scope, or not, ignoring the type of the variable.

Something like this:

```
int var1;
{ int var2; }
cout << var1Exists::value << endl; // true
cout << var2Exists::value << endl; // false, since 'var2' went out of scope
```

I've found how to [check for a non-member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375652/sfinae-to-detect-non-member-function-existence) (actually found [two ways](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.c++.moderated/sfinae-and-non-member-functions-detec/107639)), but I can't manage to do it with a simple variable.

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
namespace sfinae{
    template<typename Type>
    class variableName{

        template<void* ptr> struct lowest;
        template<typename T, typename ptr = lowest<&var1>* > struct check;

        template<typename U>
        static std::true_type tester(check<bool>*);

        template<typename U>
        static std::false_type tester(...);

    public:
        static constexpr bool value = sizeof(tester<bool>(0))==sizeof(std::true_type);
    };
}
```

Which is supposed to test if `var1` exists, and - quite obviously - doesn't compile, complaining `var1` is not declared. To be honest I'm not as fluent in using SFINAE as I would like to be, so maybe I missed something really simple.

Comment: I don't really see the usage, since you know the scope and so the variables (which is not true if you want to know the existence of member)...

Comment: I don't think this can possibly work.  No matter how sophisticated your template magic, at some point you'll need to put in the name of the identifier you'd like to check.  And if that is not in scope, it will always be a syntax error.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I'm not sure how it could be useful. You want to place this in a header, and headers are normally included at the beginning of the file, so you can only check for something that's in a header included before your own header. But dependence on the order of inclusion is a very bad thing.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't see the usage either. I'm trying to do it __for science!__ (and out of plain curiosity)

Comment: @n.m. You have a valid point there, and I'm not really sure if its possible too. That's why I've came in and asked in the first place. If its not possible - well - at least I've ended up learning something, which is always a good thing, right?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that by definition the name of the identifier you are checking must necessarily be a nondependent name, which must be looked up and in scope at template definition time, and will always cause a hard error if it's not in scope.